# Include Nuget dependencies in .exe

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I am building a Windows Forms application that can take snapshot from webcam, I'm using OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU package.

Is there a way to include this package in the .exe file ?

Thanx

Comment: The DLLs from the Nuget will get included in the output folder of the compile, but to get it built into directly into your EXE you'll have to get ahold of the source code and include the source in your project.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Costura Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to embed third-party libraries into your exe. If you can use .net core there is a new feature called [single exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables)

Comment: I was not a ware of single exe.  Good to know